# How to save any file/data in application folder in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using a library for converting HTML to PDF. After converting to PDF how can I save this converted PDF file in application folder in a controller?
Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult ABC(ResearchProposal model)
{
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    // transmit the posted data to view
    viewData["MyModel"] = model;

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    // Render the Index view in a HTML string
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "ABC", null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
            ControllerContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewData,
            new TempDataDictionary(),
            stringWriter
            );
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

    // Get the view HTML string
    string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();

    // Get the base URL
    String currentPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    String baseUrl = currentPageUrl.Substring(0, currentPageUrl.Length - "Reports/ABC".Length);

    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    // Set license key received after purchase to use the converter in licensed mode
    // Leave it not set to use the converter in demo mode
    htmlToPdfConverter.LicenseKey = "fvDh8eDx4fHg4P/h8eLg/+Dj/+jo6Og=";

    // Set an adddional delay in seconds to wait for JavaScript or AJAX calls after page load completed
    // Set this property to 0 if you don't need to wait for such asynchcronous operations to finish
    htmlToPdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 2;

    // Convert the HTML string to a PDF document in a memory buffer
    byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlToConvert, baseUrl);


    // Send the PDF file to browser
    FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(outPdfBuffer, "application/pdf");

    fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Convert_Current_Page.pdf";

    return fileresult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.WriteAllBytes` to save the bytes of the `FileContentResult` that you got.

You will need to map the relative path of the server for this to work, as relative path only works in the context of ASP.NET.

```
string filename = "Convert_Current_Page.pdf";
string path = Server.MapPath("~G/Initial try/Content/data/");
path = Path.Combine(path, filename);

File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileResult.FilecContents);
```

Comment: but it is  giving error at file.writeallbytes();   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @MuhammadSajidGhufran Oh, sorry, you need to use `System.IO` namespace. So it is actually, `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: yep. i've done it.. but now raising an exception at:  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("~G/Initial try/Content/data/" + model.Name, outPdfBuffer);                                                             Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~G\Initial try\Content\data\'

Comment: @MuhammadSajidGhufran You will need to use `Server.MapPath()` to convert a relative path to an absolute path and append the name.

Comment: Most web apps don't have the privilege to access files and folders of the host, with exception to `AppData` folder at the root folder of the web app. Otherwise, you will need to configure the file system to allow access to the folder you want.

Comment: can you plz help me out to set access rights  to folders?